# Работа с preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Прошу помочь с использованием функции preg_replace

Необходимо прописать такие условия, что бы из кода:

```
.text{}
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:transparent}
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{}
@media only screen and (max-width:940px){
   .text{test:test;}
   .text{}
}
```

Получился код:

```
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:transparent}
@media only screen and (max-width:940px){
   .text{test:test;}
}
```

То-есть все данные с пустыми {} должны быть удалены.

---

Пробовал делать вот так

```
preg_replace('/}[^{]+{}/', '}',$tetx);
```

Но так не работает.

---

**PHP 7.1**

Comment: Может, `preg_replace('~^\h*(?:(?:\[[^][]*]:)?\w+::|\.)[-\w]+{}\h*\R?~m', '', $s)`? [Работает вот так](https://regex101.com/r/akUvru/1).

Comment: не сработало, на выходе код тот же

Comment: А PHP [говорит, что работает](https://3v4l.org/MTB4C).

Comment: Все работает, просто обязано работать.

Comment: а это обязательно делать регуляркой?
может проoе просто поубивать строки в которых есть '{}'?

Comment: Да, что-то вроде `preg_replace('~^.*{}.*R?~m', '', $s)`. Только "убьёт" и `.text{some("{}")}` (не знаю, возможны ли такие строки в данном случае)

Comment: Раз я уже написал скину, может и пригодится)
'(.*\{\}.*)|(.*\{\s+\}.*)'

Будет ловить все строки где есть {} с пробелами и без, пока внутри {} не будет любого символа кроме пробелов и табуляции
например такие.
      .text{.text{.text{.text{ 
} } }}

Comment: `^.*{}`
[^.*{}](https://regex101.com/r/ocTVdw/2/)

Comment: @SergeiDimitriev, у вас останутся пустые строки, в примере у ` Wiktor Stribiżew` пустых сток не останется.